# Excel chart with twin axis

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have this data:

```
    |  km/h |    mi/h
1   | 100   | 62.13711922
2   | 120   | 74.56454307
3   | 95    | 59.03026326
4   | 80    | 49.70969538
```

where `mi/h` is calculated from `km/h` column, by dividing the cell values with 1.609344.

Now I want to plot a chart with twin Y axes, where 1st Y axis will reference `km/h` and the second `mi/h`, for the "same" data. How to do this in Excel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the KM data and create a chart, for example a line chart. The data will be plotted on the primary axis.

Select the data for the miles, including the header and copy it. Select the chart and do a paste special to paste as new series. Select the new series, format it and select "Secondary Axis". The secondary Y axis will show on the right hand side of the chart.

Now you need to adjust the maximum value of the secondary chart. Look at the maximum value on the primary X axis chart. For your data sample, with Excel's default settings, it's probably 140. Calculate the miles for that value, i.e. 86.99196691

Format the secondary axis, set the minimum to 0 and the maximum to 86.99196691

[image]

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks for the detailed explanation :)